# Detect ability to place phone calls with javascript from browser

Tags: javascript, html, mobile, browser-feature-detection

Does anyone know if there is a way to detect the ability to make phone calls from a browser/webpage?

I don't necessarily want to know if I'm dealing with a touchscreen or smaller viewport, but rather if the device or browser has the ability to make phone calls.

Essentially I want to display a clickable "Call phone number" (href="tel:+15555555555") if the device has the capacity to make phone calls, or hide the element if does not.

Comment: I doubt this is possible. Besides, the ability to place calls isn't device-specific either; `tel` links on my PC, for example, will place calls using Lync.

Comment: Looks like that's the same question indeed, I wanted to avoid a large array of browser names.

Comment: Agreed. IMHO the added feature of your call link outweighs the case where a user can't handle the link.